# wrapfigure goes outside mdframed bounds

Tags: graphics, mdframed, wrapfigure

I've looked everywhere and can't figure out why using a `wrapfigure` around an image causes it to go outside an `mdframed` environment.

#### Things I've Tried

- `tcolorbox`
- `minipage` inside/outside `wrapfigure`
- `varwidth`

#### Image

The image extends outside the frame and goes under the next list item.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

#### Code

```latex
\begin{mdframed}
    \textbf{Solution: }

    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{2.5in}
        \includegraphics[height=3in]{media/image4.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \begin{align*}
        \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{river}} &= \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{shore}}
        - \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{river}{shore}}
        \\
        \SI{-8}{\metre\per\second} &= \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{shore}}
        - \SI{5}{\metre\per\second}
        \\
        \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{shore}} &= \SI{-3}{\metre\per\second} 
    \end{align*}
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: The image is overlaid, which means that mdframed has no way to tell when it is done.

Comment: Thank you, that was the info I needed! I guess I could just do `multicol`, `minipage`, or `vspace` in cases where the text doesn't go past the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses minipages instead of wrapfig.  While it is possible to align the tops instead of the centers, you will need to use `\raisebox` on the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
    \textbf{Solution: }
    
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{2.5in}
        \includegraphics[height=3in, width=2.5in]{media/image4.png}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2.5in-\columnsep}
    \begin{align*}
        \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{river}} &= \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{shore}}
        - \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{river}{shore}}
        \\
        \SI{-8}{\metre\per\second} &= \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{shore}}
        - \SI{5}{\metre\per\second}
        \\
        \mathbf{v}_\mathrm{\frac{barge}{shore}} &= \SI{-3}{\metre\per\second} 
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```